# Counting Recursive Calls by Hand

Tags: recursion

New CS student, studying for a final.  I am trying to figure out how many times a recursive method will be called in general.  Added the code as an example.  If I input abcd and efgh, how many calls based on the size of the Strings?  If n is any data size, the # of calls is n(?) in any recursive method.

```java
public static String interweave(String s1, String s2)
{ 
   if (s1.equals("") ) return s2;
   else if (s2.equals("")) return s1;
   else return "" + interweave(s1.substring(0,s1.length()-1), s2.substring(0,s2.length()-1))
       +s1.charAt(s1.length()-1)+s2.charAt(s2.length()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in your question, at each recursive step you reduce by one the size of both strings until either one of them has length zero (the base cases of the recursion). It's easy to see that the number of recursive calls is `min(m, n) + 1`, where `m` is the initial length of `s1` and `n` is the initial length of `s2`.

For example, if `s1 = "abc"` and `s2 = "de"` it will take 2 recursive calls to traverse `s2` (the string with the minimum length) plus one extra call for exiting at the base case, therefore `min(s1.length(), s2.length()) + 1 == 3`. You can test it programmatically like this:

```
static int counter;

public static String interweave(String s1, String s2) {
    counter++;
    if (s1.equals(""))
        return s2;
    else if (s2.equals(""))
        return s1;
    else
        return interweave(s1.substring(0, s1.length()-1), s2.substring(0, s2.length()-1))
        + s1.charAt(s1.length()-1)+s2.charAt(s2.length()-1);
}

public static int count(String s1, String s2) {
    counter = 0;
    interweave(s1, s2);
    return counter;
}
```

Now when you run the following statements, the formula works as expected:

```
// s1.length() == s2.length()
System.out.println(count("abcde", "fghij"));
> 6

// s1.length() > s2.length()
System.out.println(count("abcde", "fg"));
> 3

// s1.length() < s2.length()
System.out.println(count("ab", "cdefg"));
> 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This answer is exactly what I was asking. By breaking the method down into simple terms, I can see now why each call happens and when the base case is reached to end the calls.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The characters don't mean anything just the length. You could convert this to a numeric problem as follows:

```
public static String interweave(int s1, int s2)
{ 
   if (s1 == 0) return s2;
   else if (s2 == 0) return s1;
   else return interweave(s1-1, s2-1)+2;
}
```

Comment: Reducing it down to the base case, I get (n) recursion calls and (n+1) total calls.  Am I looking at this the right way?